# unused variable 'class' [-Wunused-variable] - error/warning

Tags: c++, sdl

I have this project in C++ using SDL.

I am getting this error while compiling, and i don't know how to fix it.

it says:

```
Source/Classes/game.cpp:15:15: advarsel(this means 'warning' in danish): unused variable 'imagemanager' [-Wunused-variable]
```

but imagemanager is a Class?
This is the line causing the error:

```
Imagemanager imagemanager; // Init's class Imagemanager
```

it's placed at line 15 in file 'game.cpp'

This is 'Imagemanager';

```
class Imagemanager
{
friend class Player;
private:

public:
SDL_Surface* load_image( std::string filename ); // Loads images

//Apply a surface to another. Often used for applying surface to display
int apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip );
};
```

This is defined in a different file, but it's included properly.

EDIT:
Forgot to say that i AM using this class, but the compiler says when i use it that it's not defined
I am using imagemanager here:

```
surface = imagemanager.load_image("player.png";);
```

This is in another class named

```
Player
```

and initialized as

```
player
```

Both the classes(imagemanager and player) gets initialized in the constructor of the class Game and game is initialized in main. i use imagemanager in player and plan to use it elsewhere too.
Main file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"

#include "Classes/game.cpp"

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
{
    Game game;
    game.initialize(); // Initializes the rest of game
    game.go(); // Starts the game
    return 0; // Ends the program
}
```

Game.cpp's constructor + header files:

```
#ifndef _GAME_
#define _GAME_
#include "imagemanager.cpp"
#include "player.cpp"
#include "timer.cpp"
#include "game.h"

Game::Game()
{
    screenDimension.w = 940; // Width  of the initialized window
    screenDimension.h = 540; // Height of the initialized window
    useFrameCap = true; // Tells the frame cap wether to activate or not
    quitGame = false; // Tells the main loop to quit if true
        FPS = 60; // Frames per second. Used by the frame cap.
    Imagemanager imagemanager; // Inits class Imagemanager
    Player player; // Inits class Player
    Timer timer; // Inits class Timer
    Game game; // Inits class Game
}
```

Later in "game.go()" i call the function "player.render()" and after that "player.update()":

```
if ( RunJumpF )
    {
        RunJumpF = player.jump();
    }
```

RunJumpF is getting true when right is pressed or when the function wants to be run at next tick

After all the other calculation of other things i call:

```
player.update();
```

My player.cpp file with the actual functions looks like this:

```
#ifndef __PLAYER__
#define __PLAYER__
#include <string>
#include "player.h"

Player::Player()
{
    surface = imagemanager.load_image("player.png";); // Loads the player tile and saves into the surface 'surface'
    if (surface == NULL) // in case something went wrong in loading the player, tell the user
    {
        SDL_WM_SetCaption("ERROR LOADING PLAYER!", NULL); // I know there are better ways to do this but i'll look at that later
    }
    needsUpdate = true;
}

bool Player::jump()
{
    move.x = move.x + 3; // Moves the player X pixels right, next time the player updates
    needsUpdate = true; // Tells the program to update the player

    return true; // Tells the program that this function isn't done and it will be run next tick
}

int Player::update()
{
    if ( needsUpdate )
    {
        pos.x = pos.x + move.x;
        pos.y = pos.y + move.y;
        move.x = 0;
        move.y = 0;
        render(); // This calculates the position of the player and blits the player to the display
        return 1; // If no errors were discovered return 1;
    } else {
        render();
        return -1; // If no need to update, returns -1
    }
}

bool Player::render()
{
        if (SDL_BlitSurface( surface, NULL, display, pos ) != 0)
        {
            SDL_WM_SetCaption("ERROR BLITTING PLAYER!", NULL); // Tells the user that shit gone wrong
            return false;
        }
        return true
}
#endif
```

Comment: Usage is in game.cpp file? You have no `return`, before this string? Please show self-contained minimal example, that demonstrated problem (or show some of game.cpp file contents).

Comment: Are your declaration of `imagemanager` and your use of it in the same scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's warning, not error. Since you don't use your `imagemanager` object and only declare it - you have this warning. You can use for example
`(void)imagemanager;`, or really use this object (not pay attention on this warning, until you develop application) and warning will be disappeared.

EDIT: how about show us usage of this object?

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to tell the actual problem :) i have edited the post
But thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`imagemanager` is a variable(object) of type `Imagemanager`.

So, the warning is correct. Use `imagemanager` in your code somewhere, or delete the line.

Also note, C++ is case-sensitive, so there is a difference between `Imagemanager` and `imagemanager`.

One is a class in your code, and the other is an object of that type.

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to tell the actual problem :) i have edited the post